# Creating Google Cloud sql tables using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to create Google cloud sql tables using terraform.

However it seems that only google cloud sql instance and sql database creation is possible through terraform and using cloudshell we can create the sql tables.

But I am trying to create the tables using terraform only whether by directly using the sql script inside my terraform script or just referencing the sql script from the terraform script where thse sql script will be stored somewhere e.g. cloud storage.

Any leads/suggestions on the same would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your current TF script? Why it does not work?

Comment: I have not written one yet, because I am stuck at table creation. I can create db instance and db using terraform but creating the tables using terraform, that's where I was struggling how to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try out the [Provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax)

here is a simple example for Postgres

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "default" {
  [...]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -f schema.sql -p <port> -U <username> <databasename>"
  }
}
```

> Provisioners can be used to model specific actions on the local
> machine or on a remote machine in order to prepare servers or other
> infrastructure objects for service.

schema.sql would hold your table definitions.

the same way you can update this command for **MySQL** also. Make sure your local or CI/CD machine has **MySQL cli** installed so from there it will connect to **DB instance** and create the table.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, will definitely try this.

Comment: hope you get an idea of what this provisioner does. use local command line and connect with the mysql and from locally executing command you cna create table

Answer (score -1):

Provisionners are ultra ugly, but seems to be the only way to do...
I took the whole day to generate mysql schema from openapi spec in gitlab ci/cd to just come to this issue... I hope that to configure API gateway from the same openapi spec will be easier. I'm architect, I just want 1 source of truth for db, api, client and server micro-services. But I think that generating DB schema in Infra repo will avoid to use this sad bastion, that I don't want to use.

Comment: Your "Answer" looks like it is more of a comment on another person's answer?